# Script scanning and adding string to lines such as *#include "abcd.h"

Tags: bash

I want to make a script that scans source files, and add a string to header lines such as from *#include "abcd.h"* to *#include "dir/abcd.h"*. It doesn't matter what header file it is, just anything after #include. Anybody have any idea how to do it with unix commands or I should write a script?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following bash script will do it:

```
for h in *.h ; do 
    sed -i 's+#include “abcd.h”+#include “dir/abcd.h”+g' $h ; 
done
```